# Como ignorar letras maiusculas em uma estrutura de comparação

Tags: vba

Estou tentando fazer uma comparação em uma planilha e conseguir definir o range e tbm a formula condicional, porém estou incorrendo em uma erro básico que são as letras maiúsculas... para as células que contem letra maiúscula minha formula condicional não funciona.
Já tentei o `.lower()` para ignorar a maiúscula mas não esta funcionando...

```
Dim x As Integer
x = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
y = 2
z = 18
w = 17
Do While y <= x
If ActiveSheet.Cells(y, z).Value = "laranja" Or ActiveSheet.Cells(y, z).Value = "banana" Then
ActiveSheet.Cells(y, w).Value = "frutas"
End If
y = y + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Converta tudo para minúscula ou maiúscula antes de comparar, por exemplo:

```
If LCase(ActiveSheet.Cells(y, z).Value) = LCase("laranja") ....
```

Outra forma e adicionar ao início do código o [Statement Option Compare](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-compare-statement)

```
Option Compare Text
```

Isso vai fazer todas as comparações ignorar o case.